# Unable to connect to service fabric cluster through visual studio for remote debugging

Tags: azure-service-fabric, visual-studio-2019

Unable to connect to service fabric cluster through visual studio for remote debugging

I have a service fabric cluster deployed using ARM template. I am using the same cluster certificate and client certificate to connect to cluster(for development purpose only). I am able to connect to the cluster using powershell. However, when I try to connect to the cluster using visual studio cloud explorer for remote debugging, I get below error in the output window in visual studio:

Cloud Explorer could not connect to cluster 'xxxxxxxx':
An authentication token could not be obtained. Refresh the node to sign in again.

I have tried to refresh the cloud explorer but it has no effect. Additionally, I tried to deploy the service fabric application and then try, however, it has the same error before and after deployment of service fabric application.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @HaseebAhmed: I was unable to perform the remote debugging. I had to put in additional logs to move ahead with my debugging. Unfortunately, didn't receive any breakthrough in solving this issue.